# Windows server 2022 C# Remoting Authentication failed on the remote side (the stream might still be available for additional authentication attempts

Tags: c#, .net, windows, remoting, windows-server-2022

I have a Windows service that using .net remoting. It stopped working in Windows 2022, but working on all other previous Windows servers even Windows 11, there is no exception but the client is  returning

*Authentication failed on the remote side (the stream might still be available for additional authentication attempts).*

Upon inspecting the logs I noticed the IsConnectingEndPointAuthorized method was called twice. but
IsConnectingIdentityAuthorized is not called at all.

Comment: Are you solving the right problem? IIRC, Remoting was effectively deprecated over a decade ago. Whilst it still "works", it'd probably be time better spent to (finally) find a replacement for it.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever. It is legacy application I thought I would be bale to extend its use for a couple of years. I will replace the remoting part with WCF.